# How do you implement custom views similar to Conversations in OS X Lion Mail?

Tags: cocoa, view, osx-lion

I'm wondering how to implement views similar to the conversation views in mail (for Lion).

http://images.apple.com/macosx/whats-new/images/mail_conversation_screen.jpg

I want the effect where it looks like a sheet of paper laying on the background.

I'm thinking that it may just be a view based table view.

A nudge in the right direction would be fine.  Just need to know where to look to find out how to do it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It *could* be a view based table view or just a normal container view with some simple tiling logic (ie, "roll through each subview and set their frames"). The effect you're looking for, though, can be easily accomplished with layer-backed views with a background shadow enabled.

There are several perfectly valid approaches to this goal (the layout *and* drawing parts). Pick one, start down the path, then post questions as problems arise.